# getting "path error" when adding external libraries to Skulpt

Tags: matplotlib, app-inventor, skulpt

I am trying to use Python's matplotlib with Skulpt in App Inventor/Thunkable, I created a "third-party.js" file following this link https://gist.github.com/bnmnetp/20bd9105f11f2a164fc0 
and I added the file in App Inventor.

I am getting this error

> :NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest':Failed to
>   load
>   'file:///static/primeronoo/skulpt/external/matplotlib/**init**.js'.

What should I do ?

Comment: Have you seen this: [How to use App Inventor and Skulpt to run Python code](https://puravidaapps.com/skulpt.php)? The path to that library does not seem to be correct...

Comment: Indeed, that's the tutorial I followed, but it does not implement the wanted library, so I looked how to add the "matplotlib" library to Skulpt, and that's what I found.